# How to insert the output of my java application into mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

I am trying to write a twitter application. I crawled the twits, and I now have stored it in a folder called Twits. And in the folder, it has text files containing the information of the tweets like userid, text, etc. How can I insert the folder, or the output into mysql database. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am new to databases, and java itself, I have been stuck on this for a while now. Thank you.

Comment: You seem to have identified that JDBC is the Java API for databases. Read the JDBC tutorial: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/

Comment: Hi, I looked at the tutorial.I already have JDBC installed. I know the basics. But  I still can't figure out is how to get the crawled twits in to the database. How do i insert it in? Your tutorial link didn't quite teach it, it only showed how to do it manually. Thanks. Your help would be greatly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to work through a tutorial like this one: http://www.developer.com/java/data/article.php/3417381

Your goal should be to reproduce what they're doing step by step. If you understand how to do mysql with Java you can then apply your new knowledge to your Twitter app.

Have fun!

**Edit**

SQL at w3schools: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_intro.asp
PreparedStatement at Java tutorials: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: thanks. I installed JDBC. Connected it to java, and got it working. I still can't figure out how to get crawled twits in to the database. How do i insert it in? Your tutorial link didn't quite teach it, it only showed how to do it manually. Thanks.

Comment: How did you crawl the tweets? There are many, many ways. You could crawl in Java and insert the crawled tweets "manually", or you could read in your files and again insert them one by one. Either way you have to understand how to do it by hand in order to be able to automate it

Comment: you mean creating a PreparedStatement for an INSERT operation is not covered in the tutorial?

Comment: @pvblis .. I am trying to read from files,and insert into the database. I am trying to get real time tweets for my web app. I read the tutorials again, and i get how to do it manually. But automatically is what is giving me problems.  I checked out PreparedStatements, but i am still having difficulties as to how I can use it.

Comment: As your problems are still pretty basic, I just added two tutorial links in my answer. Hope that helps